# How to format "Fri Sep 11 2020 02:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)" to simply mm.dd.yy using Google App Script>

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to convert my date column from a google sheet from "Fri Sep 11 2020 02:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)" to simply 09.11.20. I tried this code but it does not convert and throws an error. Please advise:

```
var date1 = sheet.getRange('P2:P2').getValues(); //my date field
var date_formatted = Utilities.formatDate(date1, "GMT", "MM.dd.yy");
```

What do I need to change here?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Since you want to get only cell **P2** you should use
  `sheet.getRange('P2').getValue()` instead.
- assuming the latter returns a date object, this would probably work:

  ```
  var date1 = sheet.getRange('P2').getValue(); //my date field    
  var date_formatted = Utilities.formatDate(date1, "GMT", "MM.dd.yyyy");
  ```
- If the result you are getting is the day of yesterday, then try this:

  ```
  var date1 = sheet.getRange('P2').getValue(); //my date field    
  var df = Utilities.formatDate(date1, "GMT", "MM.dd.yyyy").split('.');
  var date_formatted = `${df[0]}.${parseInt(df[1])+1}.${df[2]}`;
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Try `var date1 = sheet.getRange('P2').getValue()`

`getValues()` returns a multidimensional array.